# Did SAGA tools get slower?

Tags: qgis, saga, osgeo4w

after a while I have updated my QGIS to 2.18.15 and I have noticed that some saga tools run very slowly. Some months ago I used the saga multilevel b-spline interpolation tool and it runs very fast. But now It needs more than two times to get the same result. Did something change regarding saga? I have the feeling that QGIS needs time to start SAGA in the background.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this a like-for-like comparison, is it taking longer than it did before on the same amount of data? If you upgraded QGIS recently you maybe using a different version of SAGA now (2.3.2 rather than 2.2.x). Also try [running it from command line](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.1.3/grid_spline_4.html) to see if that makes any difference? (I doubt it, but worth a try?)

Comment: Before the update it run pretty well but after updating qgis+saga (OSgeo4w installation) it runs slowly.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same. Currently I am using SAGA 2.3.2 in QGIS 2.18.15 (mostly within python plugins). Tools that used to run quick (such as Interpolation Tools or the raster calculator) are now taking forever to give out results. I compared with identical data sets. I would simply change the SAGA Version but QGIS does not allow this any longer, it seems.

Comment: i think from 2.18.10 onwards Processing requires that you use SAGA 2.3.2 . You can still use 2.2 from the command line, just not from inside Processing.

Comment: That's a very interesting idea and I would like to try it. Could you provide an example of how this can be done from the command line? Tanks!